# Removing "undefined" in pre populated url form link (from Modified Google Expense Report script)

Tags: url, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've modified the standard google drive expense report system to use it as a competency and experience matrix where the manager can approve/reject a form.
The problem i'm encountering is when a form is rejected by the manager it sends a link back to the employee with a link to a form pre-populated by the url.

However if the employee didn't enter a value in the original form the url populates it as "undefined".

Question, can I pre-populate a form via url removing or replacing the "undefined" values?

Perhaps the code will explain better than I can.

```
+ "<P><b>" + 'Please re-submit your form <a href=' + USER_FORM_URL +
'&entry_2=' + encodeURIComponent(row.forename) + '&entry_3=' +
encodeURIComponent(row.surname) + '>here</a></b>'
```

Any help would be much appreciated, struggled to find a solution "out there".

Tom

image link http://s11.postimage.org/dyd1olkoz/url_stack.jpg as i'm a new poster.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how the standard report works or built-in workflow features in Google Docs.  Can you post a link to that template report (there appear to be a few expense reports)?  If you can post a link to yours, that would be an even more direct help.  In the meantime, tentatively assuming the url bears the data, can you replace, say, `row.forename` with `"blahblah"` and see if that is reflected in the linked-to form?

Comment: @BrianHenry Henry Here's the [link to the tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/expense_report_approval) the snippet of code is inserted above the MailApp command.
And here's the [link to the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/a/nomenca.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0At4KUfCTYj6OdDJoTkNSLWNVUzN3ZVNoR1VzTWoxZ1E&output=html)
Happy to add as collab if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `getObjects()` function in the script may skip adding a value to the `row` object, later used in `sendReportToManager()`, if the value is empty in the expense report spreadsheet.  So, later trying to append something like `row.bananas` (or something empty in sheet and thus not defined on object) will result in 'undefined' being appended to the string instead.  If you look at your querystring for the form with the 'undefined' values, you should see 'undefined' in the url's querystring.

You can avoid this by wrapping your `encodeURIComponent(row.XXXX)` calls for potentially empty columns to be something like this: `row.XXXX ? encodeURIComponent(row.XXXX) : ""`

So, replace the likes of:

```
+ "<P><b>" + 'Please re-submit your form <a href=' + USER_FORM_URL + 
'&entry_2=' + encodeURIComponent(row.forename) + '&entry_3=' +
```

with

```
+ "<P><b>" + 'Please re-submit your form <a href=' + USER_FORM_URL + 
'&entry_2=' + (row.forename ? encodeURIComponent(row.forename) : "") + '&entry_3=' +
```

Comment: Brain, thank you, that essentially ifblank statement has resolved my problem. It all seems too obvious now in hindsight, but that's what learning another language is all about. 

Many Thanks, Tom.